# in vbscript how to access XML file opened in a function in another function

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript

In the below code, log file can be accessed by addchild function. How can I access the same log file using vbscript and XML .I'm trying write data in a XML file instead of notepad

```
function open_log_file(project_id)
user_id = Rights.GetCurrentUser()
username= ucase(Data.GetAttributebyId(user_id, “nameshort”) )
P_name = Data.GetAttributebyId(project_id, “name”)
P_name = REMOVE_SPECIAL_CHARACTER(P_name)
‘Folder_Path=”\\Tmllknwskc05555\dpe_export_data\USER_LOG\” & P_name
Folder_Path=”\\Tmllknwskc05555\dpe_export_data\USER_LOG\” & P_name
Set fso = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)
If fso.FolderExists(Folder_Path) = False Then
Set fl= fso.CreateFolder(Folder_Path)
ELSE
Folder_Path=”\\Tmllknwskc05555\dpe_export_data\USER_LOG\” & P_name
‘Folder_Path=”\\Tmllknwskc05555\dpe_export_data\USER_LOG\” & P_name
End IF
FilePath=Folder_Path & “\” & username & “_” & P_name & “.txt”
If fso.FileExists(FilePath) = False Then
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath, True)
Else
Set filL = fso.GetFile(FilePath)
Set ts = filL.OpenAsTextStream(8)
End If
set open_log_file = ts

Set wshShell = CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”)
strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( “%COMPUTERNAME%” )
ts.Write strComputerName

end function

function sa_addchild(parent_id, childname, childlistname) ‘run for ergocomporgproduct
parent_name = Data.GetAttributebyId(parent_id, “name”)
project_id = Data.GetAttributeByID(parent_id,”ergoproject”)
set ts=open_log_file(project_id)
ts.Write”" & time & ” ” & Date & ” Node(Add Child) ‘” & Data.GetAttributeByID(childname, “name”) & “‘ Added on ‘” & parent_name & “‘” &Vbcrlf
ts.close
end function
```

Comment: Please fix and format your code. This is syntactically broken and completely unreadable. *P.S.: How did you manage to get smart quotes in there, other than blindly copying it from a broken blog post?*

Comment: @bond: Smart quotes (aka fancy quotes, curved quotes) are `“ ” ‘ ‛ ’`. Most programming languages, including VBScript, use straight quotes: `" '`. Code with smart quotes is broken; it won't compile/run.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following XML file and I want to add a new child inside ComputerAudit.How to do this using VBScript ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<ITChecklist>
-    <ComputerAudit>
        <ComputerName>atl-ws-001</ComputerName>
        <AuditDate>6/24/2014</AuditDate>
     </ComputerAudit>
</ITChecklist>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? To post a new question, post a new question. To post an answer, post the answer (not a different question) as an answer. To comment, post a comment at the right place. To edit or expand your question, edit your question. It's as simple as that. If you don't stick to those basics, you won't get any good answers, and rightly so.

Comment: actually the above question is related to this one.

Comment: Then post it as a separate question, and point to this one. Don´t post answers which are in fact related questions.